# Sumifs Formula using Multiple Arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops, sumifs

I am trying to create a sumifs formula which contains multiple arrays in VBA. The code is as follows:

```
MyArray(1) = "A"
MyArray(2) = "B"
MyArray(3) = "C"
MyArray(4) = "D"

Set SumArray(1) = Range("E:E")
Set SumArray(2) = Range("F:F")
Set SumArray(3) = Range("G:G")

For i = 1 To UBound(MyArray)
For j = 12 To 14
For y = 1 To UBound(SumArray)



Cells(i + 7, j + 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(SumArray(y),Range("A:A"), "Unknown", Range("B:B"), MyArray(i)) + _
WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(SumArray(y), Range("A:A"), "Medical", Range("B:B"), MyArray(i))

Next y
Next j
Next i
```

I have the code almost working the way I need. The problem is that for SumArray(y), it is calculating all cells using the last range in the array. I need it to use the first range in the first column, second range in the second column, etc.

I apologize if any of this is unclear, I am a coding novice and this is my first time posting. If there is anything I can do to clarify my question, please let me know! Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: It is calculating all of them, just writing them all in the same cell since `(i + 7, j + 1)` doesn't change with changing values of `y`

Answer (score 1):

You are not adding the results from the previous loop to the subsequent loops, just overwriting the previous.

```
MyArray(1) = "A"
MyArray(2) = "B"
MyArray(3) = "C"
MyArray(4) = "D"

Set SumArray(1) = Range("E:E")
Set SumArray(2) = Range("F:F")
Set SumArray(3) = Range("G:G")

For i = 1 To UBound(MyArray)
    For j = 12 To 14
        Cells(i + 7, j + 1).Value = 0
        For y = 1 To UBound(SumArray)
            Cells(i + 7, j + 1).Value = Cells(i + 7, j + 1).Value + WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(SumArray(y), Range("A:A"), "Unknown", Range("B:B"), MyArray(i)) + _
            WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(SumArray(y), Range("A:A"), "Medical", Range("B:B"), MyArray(i))
        Next y
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you for your help so far! I think this code is closer to what I need. The code you gave is resulting in a sum of all the ranges in the three columns, but I need something slightly different. I need the first loop to calculate based on sumarray = Range("E:E"), the second to calculate based on sumarry = Range("F:F"). In other words, all of the column results should be different. Thanks!